# How to use query parameters in Django Swagger Documentation?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, swagger

Let's assume that we have for example such URL - `localhost:8000/object?name=STH`. Anyone have an idea how can I display `object` with `name` equals `STH` using Django Swagger Documentation?

```
class ObjectList(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            t = request.GET['sth']
            object = Object.objects.filter(sth=sth)
        except:
            object = Object.objects.all()
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am trying in this way but it's not visible in my Swagger:

URL: `url(r'^object-data$', views.ObjectList.as_view()),`

```
class ObjectList(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('sth', )
```

At this moment my Swagger looks as shown below. I would like to have `sth` instead of `pages`. I have no idea why it is there.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [djang-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/rest_framework.html) package that integrates nicely with rest framework and it also has support for swagger docs, you get auto-generated filtering columns for that endpoint in swagger.

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class ObjectList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('sth', )
```

Comment: I am trying to use it without results. I added an example GenericAPIView to the first post. Can you show me how it should be done on this example and I will map it to the rest of my views?

Comment: I added a sample for your view. You should first install `pip install django-filter` and add 'django_filters' to your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I have tried your genericAPIView but it's not visible in Swagger. It doesn't return anything. Are you sure this is equivalent of my view from the first post?

Comment: sorry my bad, you should subclass `ListAPIView` . You should also have an url pointing to this view.

Comment: Unfortunately after changes I get error `AssertionError at /object-data
'ObjectList' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.` I have added my URL to the first post.

Comment: Include the queryset then :)

Comment: I have to add queryset to `class ObjectList(GenericAPIView):`? I am trying to change `page` to `sth` from screenshot from the first post.

Comment: The `page` is added because you specified the default pagination. `sth` should be bellow page. Once you have added the queryset you should not get the `AssertionError` anymore,

Comment: Is it possible to hide `page` and leave only `sth`?

Comment: `page` is there because you have default pagination set. So it acts as a filter parameter `?page=1` . If you are sure you don't need pagination look into your django settings.py file and remove it. You should have something like this `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}`

Comment: I think you may also hide it, if you specify yaml config file in your api docs view. Check this: http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.3.x/yaml.html

Comment: I did it using `'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': None,` in `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings. Thank you very much for your help. You solved my problem.