# Django REST Framework Schema parameters list in the ViewSet action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi

I want to generate swagger (OpenAPI) schema for my DRF project.

How can I add query parameters specification to the generated schema?

Take a look at FileViewSet.list method. Here `request.GET` parameter `project` should be documented (required), but automatic schema generation misses it.

Here is example api project:

```
# views.py

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('name', 'id', 'project')


class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        project = request.GET.get("project", None)

        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(project=project)


router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'^file$', FileViewSet)


# OpenAPI Schema generation

class SwaggerRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/openapi+json'
    format = 'swagger'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        codec = OpenAPICodec()
        return codec.dump(data)

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    title='API',
    public=True,
    renderer_classes=[SwaggerRenderer],
    authentication_classes=[],
    permission_classes=[AllowAny],
    patterns=router.urls,
)

api_urls = router.urls + [url(r'^schema$', schema_view, name="schema")]
```

And then inluding `api_urls` in the `urls.py`:

```
# urls .py

from .views import api_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/', include(api_urls, namespace="v1")),
]
```

There is [DRF coreapi ManualScheme docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#manualschema) for manually documenting APIView to add custom fields, but there is no documentation for ViewSet's.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way as `ManualSchema` works for `APIView`, there is `AutoSchema` which works with `ViewSet`. It allows to describe custom and override automatically generated `path` parameters like `id`.

For example:

```
import coreapi
import coreschema
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema

...

class YourViewSet(..., ViewSet):

    schema = AutoSchema(
        manual_fields=[
            coreapi.Field(
                'id',
                required=True,
                location='path',
                description='A unique integer value identifying specific your-model-name.',
                schema=coreschema.Integer(),
                ),
        ]
    )
```

This will add (or in this case override) path parameter `id` to schema and generate validation in swagger.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have configured it a bit wrong. What I did in my project was to import `get_swagger_view` from `rest_framework_swagger.views` and added the view to the project urls and it worked like a charm.

**Example**:

```
# project/urls.py

from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='My API')

urlpatterns = [
    # other urls...
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
]
```

Ref: [Swagger Docs](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start)

**Note**: `get_swagger_view` is a shortcut to get the basic configurations. See [advanced usage](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema/) section to get more control.

Comment: And what about configuring query parameters? In this way, I will get only basic config.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222078/how-to-use-query-parameters-in-django-swagger-documentation) question.